# Is there a way to rename cities in Civilization 6?

Tags: civilization-6

In prior versions of Civilization, it was possible to rename my civilization's cities (though it was, admittedly, difficult to find in Civ V).

In Civilization VI, however, I've looked through every city management panel I can see, and can't find any sort of edit link or button for the city name. I've even tried right-clicking and double-clicking anywhere I see a city name, with no success.

Is there a way to customize my city names in Civ VI, and if so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

City Renaming has been added with the Fall 2016 update:

[image]

Open the city details pane (the highlighted page icon on the panel) and click on the city name in the top left corner of the screen

Answer (score 3):

http://steamcommunity.com/app/289070/discussions/0/340412122411024672/

Apparently it's an issue they'll fix in an upcoming patch.

Comment: I realize that one of the comments said this, but it would be very helpful if you could find a source for this. I have seen many comments claim that updates are coming "in a patch" that were never actually promised by the developers.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the city names txt in the assets folder.

http://www.gamepur.com/guide/24727-easiest-way-raname-city-name-civilization-vi.html

Comment: He wants to know how to rename cities already created.  Not the city name files.

Comment: It's a partial solution, at least – though yeah, I generally want to rename cities as I create them, usually in a multiplayer game where my friends and I often come up with silly city naming themes. If I edited this file, though, would my friends see my custom names in a multiplayer game, or would they see whatever their city names file shows?